# Quantum teleportation + time dilation = time travel?

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation, time-travel

Thought of this a while back and thought it was pretty funny, not sure if there's been similar ideas discussed elsewhere.

[image]

I can think of at least 2 reasons this won't work:

1) As far as I know, "quantum teleportation"  isn't capable of classical communication, even one way (it's more like, if we look at spins for both particles at the same time, they'll be the same, but we can't influence them directly).

2) Let's say classical communication was possible and you essentially had two entangled particles acting as two ends of a walkie talkie. If you play a regular pulse sound into the stationary (blue) end, while the red is accelerating towards the speed of light, it would probably simply hear the signal speed way up. Whenever red stops or starts, it's never actually out of sync with the signal from blue, it's only receiving it at different rates. The "time travel" with time dilation is not instantaneous, it's gradual, so nothing is ever actually "ahead" of anything else. Or something...

Could be a cool movie though...

Comment: What is the difference between "a  particle" and "a particle from the past"?

Comment: They're two entangled particles. If one is moving at the speed of light and the other is stationary, time passes more slowly for one than the other. When they both come to a stop again and time moves at the same speed, one will be "older" than the other. What effect, if any, does entanglement have on this? IE, is the younger particle still entangled with a younger twin?

Comment: If they start off in state $\xi$, and evolve unitarily, then they are eventually in state $(U_t\otimes 1)\xi(1\otimes V_T)$ where $t$ and $T$ are the proper times that have elapsed for the two particles and $U$ and $V$ are the corresponding unitary operators.  What is the question?

Comment: But aren't the left side and right side of that state now in two different times?

Comment: First, an entangled state does not have a "left side" and a "right side"; that's exactly what it means to be entangled.   As for the bit about being "in two different times", I haven't the foggiest idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm not explaining myself clearly. Left side/right side refers to your state equation, but it doesn't matter.


Super simply:


Take 2 entangled particles A and B.
B is moving at speed of light, A is stationary.
Time will pass slower for B than for A.


If communication via quantum teleportation were possible (which it's not), what happens to any signal between A and B in this situation? Wouldn't there, at the least, be some kind of signal stretching?

Comment: One of my favorites: https://xkcd.com/465/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking of the entangled state as two objects, one of which is stationary With respect to us and one of which is moving at near $c$ With respect to us. Viewed this way it is natural to think that one object must be time dilated With respect to the other.

However the entangled state is not two objects - it is a single extended object described by a single wavefunction that is a function of both space and time. There is no sense in which the blue particle is near us and the red one far from us. Both particles are delocalised equally over the whole region covered by the wavefunction.

To write down the wavefunction we need to choose a coordinate system and the most natural one is to place ourselves at the origin. Then the spatial coordinates are distance measured by our rulers and the time coordinate is measured by our clock. One we define these coordinates we can write the wavefunction as $\Psi(\mathbf{x}, t)$.

You could of course choose a different coordinate system, which in your case would presumably be one with the origin moving away from us at some high velocity, and you would then write the wavefunction as $\Psi(\mathbf{x}', t')$. It would be the same wavefunction as before, just written down using different coordinates.

In general the $t$ coordinate in our system will not be the same as the $t'$ coordinate in the moving coordinate system, but that doesn't matter. What you suggest is to use the $(\mathbf{x}, t)$ coordinates to describe the end of wavefunction near us but the $(\mathbf{x}', t')$ coordinates (or possibly you mean mixed coordinates $(\mathbf{x}, t')$) to describe the far end. Unsurprisingly this isn't physically meaningful.

Comment: Thanks John, that's helpful. I'm still confused though. How is there no sense that the blue particle is near us and the red one far from us? This upsets my whole mental model (which is good). But what are they talking about here? http://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.07831.pdf It seems like distance and manipulation of particles is a key interest here. And as far as I know, every particle at every instant has a position in space, and that evolves nonlinearly according to Schrodinger's equation. Not so? Or perhaps because of the nonlinearity of Schrodinger's equation, "distance" also evolves nonlinearly?

Comment: @Davebs: *every particle at every instant has a position in space* - no, no, no, no, no, no, no! A particle is described by some wavefunction $\psi(\mathbf{x}, t)$ and the probability of finding the particle in any infinitesimal volume element $dV$ is $\psi^*\psi\,dV$. The particle is delocalised across the region of space where $\psi$ is non-zero - it simply does not have a position in the sense we think of the position of a macroscopic object.

Comment: Ok, this most clearly explains what I was talking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel#Using_wormholes so I'm not completely crazy! I should learn to use google more.